# .htaccess script

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want any requests with any extra "words"[paths] (e.g., www.mysite.com/words/index.html, etc.)just to be directed to my "index" page. If the word index is in the url, I want the page to be direct to the /.

Presently I have:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.html

RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It directs pages that have index.html in the url, but not pages that may have variants [additional paths]like:
www.mysite.com/words/index.html. In other words, somebody that may be looking for an index on the page "words" types this in their browser to look for the "index" of the "words" page. They should go to www.mysite.com/. Instead, it directs to the real page if it exists, but just shows text--not pics and other items on the page. Again, I don't want a partial page display, just redirected to the index page, which is /.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want

> http://www.mysite.com/index.html

to redirect to

> http://www.mysite.com/

and

> http://www.mysite.com/words/index.html

also to redirect to

> http://www.mysite.com/

It seems to me a simple way to do that would be

```
RewriteRule index\.html$ http://www.mysite.com/ [R,L,NC]
```

Have I missed something?